# True Random Number Generating

Tags: vb.net, random, numbers, generator

So basically, I have this function that is supposed to generate two random integers between a high and a low number, to make a point on the form. I know that Random can handle this, but Random has consistency, whereas I need the numbers to be completely random on the form.

For example, most of my generated points appear in a diagonal line. This is what I want to avoid. It should go all over the form between the high and low numbers.

Here is my current function:

```
Function GetNewLocation() As Point
    Randomize()
    Dim int1 As Integer = RandomNumber(6, 345)
    Randomize()
    Dim int2 As Integer = RandomNumber(35, 286)
    Return New Point(int1, int2)
End Function

Function RandomNumber(ByVal low As Integer, ByVal high As Integer) As Integer
    Randomize()
    Return New Random().Next(low, high)
End Function
```

How can I get true random number generation where the point is not on a diagonal line?

Comment: Computers can not generate truly random numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each time you create a new instance of `Random` you are resetting the random number generator. Since the default constructor uses `Environment.TickCount` as the seed you are often returning precisely the same sequence of pseudo-random numbers. The system does not update `TickCount` that often. This is why it seems to you that you are getting non-random numbers.

Try changing your code like this:

```
Private _rnd As New Random()
Function RandomNumber(ByVal low As Integer, ByVal high As Integer) As Integer
    Return _rnd.Next(low, high)
End Function
```

Comment: This fixed my issue, but the `Randomize` is already called on the Form_Load. I now realize that the issue was I was calling a `New Random()` on every loop.

Comment: @user2255552 - I didn't touch the call to `Randomize()`. It doesn't appear to be related to the actual generation of the random numbers.

Comment: Randomize used with Random doesn't make sense.  Randomize was for use with the old random number generator.

Answer (score 0):

There is no true randomness in computer systems. There are many algorithm to generate "random" numbers but they are always based on a seed, like the time, process id, a mix of both, or on more advanced cases where randomness is taken seriously, on sounds being detected in a microphone, data from atmospheric sensors or cosmic microwave background, but it will always derivate from some existing source of information.

Comment: Is there any way that I can at least make it avoid a diagonal line?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but you can drop this inbuilt `RandomNumber()` and try some other algorithm like the SFMT http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister

Comment: When I say diagonal line, I have a button that moves to the new location that is generated, on the form. Each point I generate, is on a diagonal line that crosses through the form.

Comment: This is not the issue.  The program is misusing `Randomize`.

Comment: I've removed all but one instance of `Randomize` and it still appears in a diagonal.

Answer (score 0):

Thats also not the best slution.
I prefer my own code:

```
 Dim old As Integer = 6572
Public Function Rand(ByVal min As Integer, ByVal max As Integer) As Integer
    Dim random As New Random(old + Date.Now.Millisecond)
    old = random.Next(min, max + CInt(IIf(Date.Now.Millisecond Mod 2 = 0, 1, 0)))
    Return old
End Function
```

Thats a little bit better

Answer (score 0):

I literally just came up with this solution. Maybe it will help =)

I went from:

```
Dim rand As Random = New Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond)
```

To

```
Dim rand As Random = New Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond * DateTime.Now.Second * DateTime.Now.Minute * DateTime.Now.Hour)
```

And it seems to have worked really well.
You can see the difference in the side by side.

[image: Random Compare]

Answer (score 0):

in java(assuming the limit is (limit-1)):

```
random  = System.currentTimeMillis()%limit;
```

You get the idea :)