# generating random numbers in visual basics

Tags: vb.net, random, numbers

I  am using a random number generator in my program, however it keeps returning the same value (0.71) every time i run the program.

code:

```
number = FormatNumber(Rnd(1), 2)
    rdmlabelTxt.Text = number.ToString
```

is there a way to produce a different random number when starting the program?
thanks.

Comment: NET has a easier to use `Random` class...

Comment: Read the docs - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7s023d2(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [True Random Number Generating](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19672483/true-random-number-generating)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call to Rnd() generating the same number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34644576/call-to-rnd-generating-the-same-number)

Answer (score 1):

According to [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7s023d2(v=vs.90).aspx) "the same number sequence is generated" when you don't give a parameter. The article also suggests to "Before calling Rnd, use the Randomize statement without an argument to initialize the random-number generator with a seed based on the system timer."

I think this will solve your issue - let us know.

Answer (score 0):

You are required to write a for loop to be able to generate different numbers

```
For i = 1 to 100
number = FormatNumber(Rnd(1), 2)
Cells(i, "A").Value = number
next i
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use Randomize() call before your codes.

```
Randomize()
Dim number As Double = 0
number = FormatNumber(Rnd(1), 2)
rdmlabelTxt.Text = number.ToString
```

Comment: You should make it clearer that `Randomize()` should only be called once in the whole program. But then your answer will be the same as Mark's, so unfortunately you are not adding any value to this post.